# how to count no of likes,shares and reviews of a facebook page in php

Tags: php, sdk

I have tried to get number of  likes and shares of a facebook page in php. But I didn't get any proper solution for it.Please anyone can suggest me full code to get all these stuffs.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `anyone can suggest me full code`, SO is not coding service.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post examples of what you have tried? Have you looked into the Graph API?

Comment: yes.,I have looked into it.but I didn't get any solution to count number of shares and likes

Answer (score 0):

Using the Graph API you can retrieve the number of likes for a Facebook page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

In terms of "shares" as in how many times the page has been sent to another person by another it would depend on the tool you are using to share the page; Facebook doesn't track this itself within it's Graph API.

If you have a link on your page that says "Share our Facebook page" you could create something in ajax that would increment a counter on how many times someone had clicked that link, or if you are using a specific plugin to share the page you might be able to use their API to get some sort of count.

Again there is very little information on this question as to the problem you are experiencing, but hopefully this will give you the jumping off point to get started.